# How to fix browser not opening in debug mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, outlook-web-addins

I am unable to start my web add-in in google chrome or any other browser I clicked on start button which have written IIS Express instead of start it goes into debug mode after clicking the button but nothing happens.
Here is screenshot before starting :

[image]

after start mode :

[image]

Comment: Check this setting in your web project's settings and ensure it's not set to "don't open a page". [image](https://i.imgur.com/Q7EMa61.png)

Comment: Thanks alot I set it to start a URL to this :http://localhost:51418/ but now page is getting open but error is coming  :  HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: please check the posted solution.

Answer (score 5):

In VS2022 you can check/uncheck a flag to launch the web project in the default browser.

To do this, right click on the relevant project in your solution and click Properties. In the menu on the left click Debug, then 'Open debug launch profiles UI'.

[image]

In the dialog which appears, select the relevant profile on the left pane, then scroll down to 'Launch browser'. Check/uncheck this option as required.

[image]

Alternatively, open the Properties/launchSettings.json file within the project and add the following line under the relevant `profiles` entry:

```
"launchBrowser": true,
```

Comment: Worked perfect in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check this setting in your web project's settings and ensure it's not set to "don't open a page"

[image]

and the reason behind the HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error is the directory browsing feature is turned off. you can enable by following below steps:

Open a command prompt, and then go to the IIS Express folder on your computer. For example, go to the following folder in a command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express
```

Type the following command, and then press Enter:

```
appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason is the your visual studio is not run as **ADMIN**. You must run visual studio with Administrator Privilege's - to do that on the short cut icon of Visual studio, right click and "run as administrator" - or for permanently check that go to Properties, Click Advanced, then click "Run as administrator" - When you run it this way you see a Label "ADMIN" on the right up corner of the VS.

Now if this is not work, alternative you can run get into the debugger using this call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`

Create an empty page and make this call on PageStart, then just load this page from your browser

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```